# "invalid version format" p.nettyException with play 2.2.1

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.2

My routes file looks like

```
GET     /                           controllers.Application.index()
POST    /get_token                  controllers.Application.getToken()
```

GET for '/' works fine.
However, POST for '/get_token' fails with following error message.

```
[error] p.nettyException - Exception caught in Netty
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid version format: =Dￆﾒ$_!HBﾕHￃ￝W(￀+￀/ﾞￌￌ￀
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.<init>(HttpVersion.java:102) ~[netty.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.valueOf(HttpVersion.java:62) ~[netty.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpRequestDecoder.createMessage(HttpRequestDecoder.java:75) ~[netty.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:189) ~[netty.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:101) ~[netty.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:500) ~[netty.jar:na]
```

I am using play-2.2.1.
I am relatively new to play.
Can some one help me out?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

Are you connecting via https? If so, you may not have a certificate set up.

The simplest fix would be to connect via http instead of https. If you really want https, though, you could generate a self-signed certificate:

`keytool -genkey -alias MyKey -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore keystore.jks
play -Dhttps.port=9443 -Dhttps.keyStore=keystore.jks -Dhttps.keyStorePassword=password run`